# how to autoincrement varchar datatype depending upon the product detail's name using trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a product details table, the fields in the table are *Prod_Id, Product_Name, Quantity, Prefix, Slno*. Now i have created trigger for varchar data type field and implemented auto increment for Prod_Id (Primary key) and for Slno. The output will be

Prod_Id -->>> PROD0001, PROD0002 and so on. Now if the product name is RACK it should create a id RACK_001 with the start two letters of the product name and auto increment automatically. For all Product name it should create accordingly,how to do this.

As of now i am using a trigger for auto increment in varchar data type. Help with the trigger code.

```
   DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER tg_product_details_INSERT
    BEFORE INSERT ON product_details
    FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
    INSERT INTO product_details_seq VALUES (NULL);
    SET NEW.Created_Date = NOW();
    SET NEW.Submitted_Date = NOW();
    SET NEW.Slno = coalesce((select max(Slno) from product_details), 0) + 1;
    SET NEW.Prod_id = CONCAT((NEW.Prefix), LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
  END
    DELIMITER ;
```

**product name -->> BOOK, SHOE, DRESS, FURNITURE**

for all **book** it should create a auto increment id **BOOK_001, BOOK_002** and for all **Shoe** it should create a auto increment id like **SHOE_001, SHOE_002** and so on...!!!

Thanks, 
Acube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the the Product Name using `NEW.Product_Name`.

Find the substring, i.e. the first two letters. Refer this [link](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php).

Then concat the result with while doing a `SET NEW.Prod_id = ...`

```
CONCAT('PROD', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
```

Comment: SET NEW.Product_Name = SELECT Product_Name, SUBSTRING( Product_Name,1,2 ) FROM product_details; SET NEW.Prod_id = CONCAT('PROD', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));   But this doesn,t work, showing me errors.

Comment: SET NEW.Prod_id = CONCAT('PROD', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));SET NEW.Prod_id = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(NEW.Product_Name,1,2), NEW.Prod_id)); Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It works fine, Thanks TechnoBrat, there is a extra bracket in the end of the code. Now i am getting the output as **ROPROD001**. I need it like **"PROD_RO001"**. Is it possible.

Comment: Yes just fiddle with the code here and there. Play with the Concat and sub strings functions you should be able to do it.

Comment: product name -->> **BOOK**, SHOE, DRESS, FURNITURE for all book it should create a auto increment id **BOOK_001**, **BOOK_002** and for all Shoe it should create a auto increment id like **SHOE_001**, **SHOE_002** and so on...!!! Help me with the code using trigger. Thanks, Acube

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing an `insert` into the same table?  I think the rest of the code should work, without that:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_product_details_INSERT
    BEFORE INSERT ON product_details
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.Created_Date = NOW();
  SET NEW.Submitted_Date = NOW();
  SET NEW.Slno = coalesce((select max(Slno) from product_details), 0) + 1;
  SET NEW.Prod_id = CONCAT('PROD', NEW.SLno, 3, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is manually setting up the `slno` and the `prod_id` using the same value, which should be one larger than the value in the table.  I suppose that you *could* also query the metadata for the next auto-increment value as well:

```
select AUTO_INCREMENT
from information_schema.tables
where table_name = 'product_details' and table_schema = database();
```